# Consumindo API Externa Java Spring Boot - JSON retornando nulo

Tags: java, json, api, spring-boot, rest

Estou iniciando meus estudos em Spring e estou tentando consumir uma API Externa, tudo parece estar "Ok", mas o retorno do JSON está nulo, alguém poderia me aujdar, pra ontem?

Art Institute of Chicago API: https://api.artic.edu/docs/#quick-start

Minha classe controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/controller")
public class ArtworkController {

    @Autowired
    private ArtworkService artworkService;

    @ResponseBody
    @GetMapping(value="/getArtwork/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<ArtworkDTO> getArtwork(@PathVariable("id") int id){
        ArtworkDTO artworkDTO = artworkService.getArtwork(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<ArtworkDTO>(artworkDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Classe Service

```
@Service
public class ArtworkService {

    public ArtworkDTO getArtwork(int id){
        return new RestTemplate()
                .getForEntity("https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/"
                        +id+"?fields=id,title,artist_title", ArtworkDTO.class).getBody();
    }
}
```

Classe DTO

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ArtworkDTO implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String artist_title;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getArtist() {
        return artist_title;
    }
    public void setArtist(String artist_title) { 
        this.artist_title = artist_title; 
    }
}
```

Retorno do JSON

```
{
"id": 0,
"title": null,
"artist": null
}
```

Comment: Não escrevam **Resolvido** no título das perguntas, isso interfere com nosso sistema indexação. Para indicar que uma pergunta foi solucionada apenas [aceitem uma resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/137387) como foi feito aqui.

Comment: Certo, Augusto. Obrigado pela orientação!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os campos da *api artic* estão vindo dentro de um outro objeto chamado *data*.

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 12996,
        "title": "Nathanael Dilgerus",
        "artist_title": "Gérard Edelinck"
    },
    "info": {
        "license_text": "The data in this response is licensed under a Creative Commons Zero (CC0) 1.0 designation and the Terms and Conditions of artic.edu.",
        "license_links": [
            "https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/",
            "https://www.artic.edu/terms"
        ],
        "version": "1.4"
    },
    "config": {
        "iiif_url": "https://www.artic.edu/iiif/2",
        "website_url": "http://www.artic.edu"
    }
}
```

O json acima foi retornado a seguinte chamada.

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/12996?fields=id,title,artist_title'
```

Sugestão de alteração para o seu dto

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAlias;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import lombok.Getter;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Getter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ArtworkDTO implements Serializable {
    private Data data;
}

@Getter
class Data {
    @JsonAlias(value = "id")
    private int id;
    @JsonAlias(value = "title")
    private String title;
    @JsonAlias(value = "artist_title")
    private String artistTitle;
}
```

Comment: Cara, funcionou. Eu tinha em mente que o problema poderia ser isto, mas ainda não sabia como resolver. Muito obrigado.